# How to wait until my pynput listener finishes? Python

Tags: python, pynput, listen

I've ran into this problem where I want to delete a file once my pynput listener has finished (by finished I mean that the program has closed) since the listener only stops if the program has been closed, how can I make a statement afterward the listener has stopped?

```
def on_press(key):
   print(" pressed : {0}".format(key))

with Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
    listener.join()

os.remove(file_path)
```

so basically, i want to remove the file_path afterwards the Listener has finished, but by the time the listener has finished, the whole program itself has stopped.

but i dont want to stop the listener until the app closes, so basically im asking how can i delete a file when I stop the program.

Answer (score 0):

You can use try and finally blocks to do handle such scenarios:

```py
try:
    with keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press) as listener:
        listener.join()
finally:
    os.remove(file_path)
```